# Where in the world can you tour a live nuclear reactor?

Tags: tours, factoids, where-on-earth

Are there nuclear plants that allow you to tour the facility and learn more about nuclear power while the plant is running?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer, but you can tour the Advanced Test Reactor, operatored by INL at Idaho Falls, Idaho in the U.S.A.

https://inlportal.inl.gov/portal/server.pt/community/community_outreach/265/inl_tours/1447

When I went we could even see spent fuel rods in the holding tanks that were still glowing with Cherenkov radiation!

Comment: I also cannot comment, but we recently visited a nuclear reactor being disassembled in [Vandellos I](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_nuclear_de_Vandell%C3%B3s) (not to be confused with Vandellos II). While not live, it's still active (takes many years to put it down) and it was a nice visit.

Comment: If you want to learn about physics in a reactor it might be even more interesting to visit a scientific reactor (neutron source). These reactors are a lot smaller, but work similar. They do not generate electricity, but neutrons for scientific experiments. You can visit one in Germany (Munich) http://www.frm2.tum.de/en/aktuelles/info-documents/contact/visitorsinformation/index.html

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/are-there-any-tours-or-opportunities-available-to-the-public-where-one-can-see-c

Comment: Not a live reactor, but the culham centre for fusion energy in the UK runs tours of it's fusion reactor research facility. It's quite an interesting tour.
http://www.ccfe.ac.uk/Visits.aspx

Comment: A little known fact is almost all Nuclear Power Plants (in the 'free world' anyway) will allow tours.. generally they want to promote safety and invite the public in order to do so.

Comment: This really should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 26):

You can do that in Switzerland:

- Beznau. This is the **oldest still running nuclear reactor** in the world. According to their [brochure](http://www.axpo.com/content/dam/axpo/switzerland/erleben/dokumente/axpo_KKB_prospekt_de.pdf.res/axpo_KKB_prospekt_de.pdf) you can contact the [visitor center](http://www.axpo.com/axpo/ch/de/axpo-erleben/axporama/kontakt.html) for guided tours.
- Mühleberg. They have regular [guided tours](http://www.bkw.ch/kernkraftwerk-muehleberg.html) in French or German.
- Gösgen. They have [daily tours](http://www.kkg.ch/de/i/werksrundgang-_content---1--1044.html) as well as a visitor centre.
- Leibstadt. They also have [tours](https://www.kkl.ch/besucherangebote/fuehrungen.html) and a visitor centre.

Something else along the same lines is the [ZWILAG](http://www.zwilag.ch/en/guided-tours-_content---1--1076.html), the temporary storage for radioactive waste. I visited that one and it was quite interesting.

Answer (score 23):

In the UK. [EDF Energy is opening new visitor centres at their nuclear power plants](http://www.edfenergy.com/about-us/energy-generation/nuclear-generation/nuclear-visitor-centres.shtml) across the country, specifically:

> Hunterston B in West Kilbride and Torness in Dunbar, Scotland,
>   Sizewell B in Suffolk, Hinkley Point B in Bridgwater, Dungeness B in
>   Kent and Heysham in Morecambe.
>
> The visitor centres are where you can find out more about our nuclear
>   power station operations, how we generate electricity and more about
>   EDF Energy.

It also says that pre arranged site tours are available.

> The visitor centres are open for you to visit between 09.00 and 16.00
>   Monday to Friday. All station tours require advanced booking.  Tours
>   will be available at the weekend, subject to availability and demand.

Comment: When I went to the  visitor center at sellafield, it was aimed at children and you could not see any of the side, a total waist of time.

Comment: @IanRingrose Visitors centres and site tours are very different.

Comment: What do you expect to see anyway, glowing rods?  This isn't the simpsons, the interesting mechanisms arn't visible

Comment: The tours should be good if you can get onto one. I went on a tour of Hinkley Point B about 20 years ago when my dad worked there.  I don't think we were given any special access or anything but we got to see a lot of the site including the working systems, and I found it fascinating as a teenage geek.  I remember we stood directly on top of the reactor core, where there was a little sign explaining that the radiation dose you receive up there is a fraction of what you would get outside Bridgewater town hall (which is made of [granite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granite#Natural_radiation)).

Comment: The tours of UK Magnox stations used to be really good, but since 2001 they wont let you into anything interesting anymore, and in any case I don't think there are any of those stations running anymore.

Comment: @IanRingrose I quite enjoyed my visit to the Sellafield visitor centre but I agree that it was aimed at children and I learned nothing.  Worth visiting if you are in the area but not worth travelling from afar.  I am not sure whether it is operating any more.  I drove past the plant recently and I saw no signs for it.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to commercial nuclear power plants, the world has many small university reactors used for research and education. For example, in the Los Angeles area a quick google search showed that UC Irvine has a reactor that [allows group tours](http://www.chem.uci.edu/~gemiller/reactor.html) by appointment.

Comment: Another such one is at Faculty of Nuclear Science in Prague, Czech Republic. However, I wouldn't say it "gives tours", it does, but moreorless only for local high schools.

Comment: The University of Texas at Austin also has a teaching reactor with opportunities for group tours: http://nuclear.engr.utexas.edu/index.php/netl/netl-access-a-procedures

Answer (score 13):

In France, you can [visit EDF's energy plants](http://energie.edf.com/nucleaire/visiter-nos-centrales-83749.html). You just need a valid ID (passport, ID card, etc.)

The tours are great! You can talk with technicians, engineers, plays with interactive setups to understand the processes, etc.

Comment: http://www.businessweek.com/news/2011-09-15/france-opens-doors-to-nuclear-sites-to-woo-public-post-fukushima.html  
I remembered seeing press about touring French nuclear plants

Comment: Do you need to be French?  EU?  Anyone?

Comment: No, you can have any nationality. But you need a valid ID and to book the visit in advance because there is a light investigation on your person.

Answer (score 10):

You can also visit [Kozloduy NPP](http://www.kznpp.org/index.php?lang=en&p=info_center&p1=visit_us) in Bulgaria.

> - When Kozloduy NPP can be visited?
>
>   The Information Centre is open for visitors every workday from 8 am to
>     4 pm. Visits to plant facilities are organised in workdays on a
>     year-round basis with closing time at 3.30 pm. Visits to the Main
>     Control Rooms and Turbine Halls of Units 5 and 6 are not organised
>     during annual outages (advanced information is available at Tel.: +359
>     973 7 21 00 and +359 973 7 27 68).
> - Open Door Day
>
>   Anyone who is interested in visiting Kozloduy NPP may use the
>     opportunity on Open Door Days organised biannually. The date of the
>     Open Door Day (usually Saturday) is announced in advance in the mass
>     media and on the website of the plant in Section Current Information,
>     News.

Answer (score 8):

In Australia you can [tour the Lucas Heights nuclear reactor](http://www.ansto.gov.au/Resources/DiscoveryCentre/Tours/), the only one in the nation.  Note that while it is indeed a nuclear reactor it is not a nuclear power plant, as it is dedicated to producing radioisotopes as a research facility.

Answer (score 5):

Poland doesn't have any nuclear power plants (yet), but it has a research reactor Maria in Świerk, near Warsaw, which provides tours for organized groups, targeted mostly for students.

Key information from the [web site](http://iea.cyf.gov.pl/nowa/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61&Itemid=67) (Polish only):

- all participants must be over 15
- you should announce the group at least 2 weeks in advance
- foreign citizens need to fill special application forms, which needs to be approved by the Director of the Institute for Atomic Energy POLATOM
- entry costs 10 PLN for each person (about 3.3$)

Answer (score 3):

Just east of Toronto is the [Darlington Nuclear Generating Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_Nuclear_Generating_Station). The operators [claim](http://www.opg.com/generating-power/nuclear/stations/darlington-nuclear/Pages/darlington-nuclear.aspx):

> Located in the Municipality of Clarington in Durham Region, 70 km east of Toronto, Darlington Nuclear provides about 20 per cent of Ontario's electricity needs, enough to serve a city of two million people.

That site offers a link to [a video tour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgcBMAs3jGc) of the site. Reporters and teachers have clearly been on a physical tour, since pictures and reports of the inside are easy to find, but I can't find a page online with the details. You could call or email the information centre to ask:

```
Information Centre 
Darlington Nuclear Ontario Power Generation 
Box 4000, Bowmanville, Ontario L1C 3Z8

Telephone: (905) 623-7122 Toll Free: (800) 461-0034

Email: DarlingtonNuclear@opg.com
```

Time sensitive update: I just received an email that reads in part:

> Darlington Refurbishment - Doors Open
>
> We would like to invite you and your family and friends to learn more about the Darlington Refurbishment Project, take a behind-the-scene tour of the reactor mock-up and check out the new Darlington Public Visitor Centre. Project staff will be on hand to answer any questions you may have. Pre-registration is not required.
>
> The key to project success in Refurbishment is the front-end planning. Replacing the core reactor components inside each Darlington reactor is a critical part of the refurbishment exercise. High-quality training, with the right tools, in the right environment, will help maximize efficiency and minimize costs. This is your chance to get a first-hand look at this upfront work.
>
> Please join us at the Darlington Energy Complex: 1855 Energy Drive, Courtice, ON
>
> Dates:
>
> - Tuesday Nov. 4, between 5:30 - 8 p.m. or
> - Wednesday, Nov. 5, between 5:30 - 8 p.m. or
> - Saturday, Nov. 8, between 10 a.m. - 2 p.m.
>
> Refurbishment is a significant investment and a major construction project for our company one which involves a great deal of, planning, hard work and dedication. It is a tremendous opportunity for us all to be a part of this vitally important project. A refurbished Darlington Nuclear Station will provide 30 more years of safe, clean, reliable electricity.

Answer (score 3):

There are two in Texas that I know of.

Quoting http://www.texasoutside.com/glenrose/sites.htm, "*About a mile inside the front gate of the [Comanche Peak Nuclear Power Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comanche_Peak_Nuclear_Power_Plant) is the Visitors Center, open from 9 am to 4 pm Monday through Saturday. Group tours can be arranged by reservation only. The Visitors Center offers several interactive displays and a 10-minute video explaining how nuclear power is made. The tour includes a view of a control room simulator in which reactor operators are trained, as well as a driving tour for an up-close view of Comanche Peak Power Plant. Travel north on FM 56, to the Comanche Peak Nuclear Power Plant — (254) 897-5554.*"

There's also one at the [University of Texas at Austin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Texas_at_Austin) / [Pickle Research Campus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Pickle_Research_Campus):

https://nuclear.engr.utexas.edu/netl/netl-access-a-procedures